# rails + carrierwave file uploading form arbitrary file fields count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, field, carrierwave, uploading

I need to have from 1 to 15 file fields for photos.

Now I'm uploading files with carrierwave gem building every photo object in my controller like: `N.times { @car.photos.build }` and then provide `N` file fields for photos in my view.

But `N` is static value as you can understand.

How can I generate dynamic count of file fields, like: 1 static from start and add 1 more on every user's ajax request (like user will be clicking `Add photo field` link) **and dynamically create photo object for it @car.photo.build**?

BTW, sorry for my english. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use javascript to generate dynamic fields.
Something like this, using jquery:

```
var photos_count;
jQuery(function() {
  photos_count = $('#photos_fields > field').size();
  $('#add_photo').each(function() {
    this.onclick = function(event) {
      $("#photos_fields").append("<div class='field'><label>Photo</label><input name='car[photos_attributes][" + photos_count + "][image]' type='file'/></div>");
      photos_count++;
    };
  });
});
```

You can define additional action to ajax creating photos objects, but you can`t build it.

Comment: Thanks for this method, but html generation is not the main problem, possible I should ask my question more concretely, the problem is dynamic photo object building `@car.photos.build` for every field I've added

Comment: I found that I can generate correct field name and its not required to pre-build objects, so it was just about correct `name` property of input tag, so I consider your answer correct, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer: I'm the author of the post.***

See [multiple files upload with carrierwave and nested_form](http://lucapette.me/multiple-files-upload-with-carrierwave-and-nested_form). It should help.

Comment: I've read your material and it helped when I was writing my own upload, but now I need a bit another thing, I've updated my question, maybe it will be more clear